# showing IMAGE_POST_ID and POST_IMG_PATH based on MESSAGEID

Tags: mysql, sql

I am fetching data from multiple tables all other data are fetched correctly, But   **IMAGE_POST_ID POST_IMG_PATH** fields  of post_images are not showing according to messageid of user_messages.

MY tables are

**1)post_images**

```
| IMAGE_ID |    SMALL_PIC_PATH |  LARGE_PIC_PATH |                        ADDDATE | VISIBILITY | USERID | MESSAGEID |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     i_i1 | /post/small/a.jpg | /post/img/a.jpg | January, 01 2012 00:00:00+0000 |     public |      2 |        m1 |
|     i_i2 | /post/small/b.jpg | /post/img/b.jpg | January, 01 2012 00:00:00+0000 |     public |      2 |        m1 |
|     i_i3 | /post/small/c.jpg | /post/img/c.jpg | January, 01 2012 00:00:00+0000 |     public |      2 |        m1 |
|     i_i4 | /post/small/d.jpg | /post/img/d.jpg | January, 01 2012 00:00:00+0000 |     public |      2 |        m1 |
|     i_i5 | /post/small/e.jpg | /post/img/e.jpg | January, 01 2012 00:00:00+0000 |     public |      3 |        m2 |
|     i_i6 | /post/small/f.jpg | /post/img/f.jpg | January, 01 2012 00:00:00+0000 |     public |      3 |        m2 |
```

**2)user_messages**

```
| MESSAGEID |           MESSAGE |   ADDDATE | SENTBY | VISIBILITY | USERID |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        m1 | Hello how are you | 23-2-2012 |      2 |     public |      1 |
|        m2 |            Hello  | 23-2-2012 |      3 |     public |      1 |
|        m3 |          Hiiiiiii | 23-2-2012 |      4 |     public |      1 |
```

I want to fetch all image_id and small_pic_path of relevent message id.
But with my query it is showing all image_id small_pic_path with all messageid.

This is my query

```
SELECT user_messages.messageid,user_messages.message,
user_messages.sentby,user_messages.visibility,


(
   SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(  `post_images`.`image_id` SEPARATOR ';')
    FROM  `post_images`
    JOIN user_messages
  ON `post_images`.`messageid` =user_messages.messageid
) AS  `Image_post_id`,
(
   SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(  `post_images`.`small_pic_path` SEPARATOR ';')
    FROM  `post_images`
    JOIN user_messages
  ON `post_images`.`messageid` =user_messages.messageid
) AS Post_Img_path,
(
  SELECT count(*) FROM likes
  WHERE element_id=user_messages.messageid
  )AS Total_Likes
, smsusers.fname as Msg_sender_fname,
smsusers.lname as Msg_sender_lname,
profile_pic.small_pic_path as Msg_sender_pic

FROM user_messages
      INNER JOIN smsusers ON
        user_messages.SENTBY = smsusers.id
 INNER JOIN profile_pic ON
 user_messages.SENTBY = profile_pic.userid
WHERE user_messages.userid='1';
```

This is my [query link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0fec/2)

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. There seems to be no relation between the `post_images` and `user_messages` tables. Can you write up what you want as an output?

Comment: MESSAGEID is foreign key at Post_images table. One Message at user_messages can have multiple Post_images entry

Comment: Please see [query link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0fec/2)

Comment: The only `MESSAGEID` foreign key in your sqlfiddle is on delete, not on create. Are you sure the tables have been created correctly?

Comment: No idea about the  you can correct the table

Comment: I can't correct it if I don't know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I dont think there are any problem. And there is a proper relationship betwen these two tables.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. Here I was not using `group by`